# Why Initially segmented index 0 tableview values are not loading in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, indexing, segment

I am using **`HMSegmentedControl`**. when i run the tableview  shows empty, when i tap on `index 1` then tableview shows.. now when I went to `index 0` tableview values are showing. Why initially I am not getting tableview data in `index 0`.

here is the code:

```
 import UIKit
 import HMSegmentedControl

 class PlansPrepaidViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

   let segmentedControl = HMSegmentedControl(sectionTitles: ["POPULAR", "SPECIAL RECHARGE", "TOP UP", "2G/3G/4G DATA", "FULL TALKTIME", "ROAMING"])
  var sortedArray = [Any]()

  let talktimeArray = ["26.66", "500.00","26.66", "500.00","26.66", "500.00","26.66", "500.00"]
  let validityArray = ["42 Days", "28 Days", "52 Days", "18 Days", "76 Days", "23 Days", "42 Days", "120 Days"]

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      tableView.delegate = self
      tableView.dataSource = self

      designSegmentedControl()
  }

    //for  segment
     func designSegmentedControl(){

     segmentedControl?.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 60, width: 500, height: 60)

         segmentedControl?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 4/255, green: 118/255, blue: 208/255, alpha: 1.0)
         segmentedControl?.selectionIndicatorLocation = .down
         segmentedControl?.selectionIndicatorHeight = 2.5

         segmentedControl?.indexChangeBlock = { index in
             print(index)
             if index == 0{

              self.sortedArray = self.validityArray.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }
              print("segmnent 0 \(self.sortedArray)")
             }

             if index == 1{
              self.sortedArray = self.validityArray.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending }
              print("segmnent 1 \(self.sortedArray)")
             }
          if index == 2{
                       self.sortedArray = self.validityArray.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedSame }
                       print("segmnent 1 \(self.sortedArray)")
                       self.tableView.reloadData()
          }
          if index == 3{
                       self.sortedArray = self.validityArray.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }
                       print("segmnent 1 \(self.sortedArray)")
                       self.tableView.reloadData()
          }
         }
         self.view.addSubview(segmentedControl!)
     }


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return sortedArray.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! PlansTableViewCell
              cell.layoutIfNeeded()
              cell.containerView.dropShadow()
      cell.talktimeLabel.text = talktimeArray[indexPath.row]
      cell.validityLabel.text = sortedArray[indexPath.row] as? String
      return cell
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all why is `sortedArray` declared as `[Any]`? The type is clearly

```
var sortedArray = [String]()
```

---

The table view doesn't show anything on launch because `sortedArray` is not populated.

Either insert

```
self.sortedArray = self.validityArray.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }
tableView.reloadData()
```

at the end of `viewDidLoad` or insert a line which forces to call the `indexChangeBlock` handler.

Comment: yes sortedArray is string thank you... as u mentioned if i give index 0 lines of code in viewdidload then data coming.. but `indexChangeBlock ` means  something like this `segmentedControl?.indexChangeBlock = { index in
               print(index)
            self.sortedArray = self.validityArray.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }
            self.tableView.reloadData()`  here i am not getting

Comment: Obviously the `indexChangeBlock` closure is called when the user taps on the segmented control. I don't know the class. Is there an API to set the index programmatically? If yes set the index to 0 in `viewDidLoad` which causes to call the closure..